# iAd banner never gets ad in simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, iad

```
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
```

Always gets called... and I don’t get any ads in the simulator.  Its really weird because I’ve done iAds before and they are pretty straight forward.

So far I have clean/rebuilt and downloaded the profile again.  If I don’t hide it ... it shows a blank ad.

Comment: iAds arn't supposed to be in the simulator.

Comment: iAds can most certainly be tested in the Simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "Blank ad" do you mean a black and white ad that says something along the lines of "this is a test advertisement"?  If so, that's what you're supposed to see--iAd only delivers test ads to the simulator.  Everything's fine :)

Comment: I mean the banner is empty with no content over and over.

Comment: And it looks like it loads Test Ads fine on the device... kind of a pain to test that way is all.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry.  I don't know why they wouldn't work on the simulator, they do for me :)  But I'm glad they work on the device--that's what matters, right? :)

Comment: Yea I guess... I need to get it showing up on top of the admob instead of underneath.  The weird part is I had it work in the simulator for other apps.

Comment: Ah, I would suggest layering code so that your iAd and AdMob ads are never on the screen at the same time.  What we do in our apps is this: iAds have a lower fill rate but pay more, so we check first if we have an iAd. If so, we show the iAd.  If not, we hide the iAd and show the AdMob ad.  Repeat as necessary :)

Comment: I think I’m going to try AdMob Mediation it looks like you can set it to do iAds now as well.